# SSL сертификат на Selectel. Certbot

Tags: node.js, ssl, pm2, certbot

Всем привет, возникла проблема с certbot. Он требует домен и субдомен, можно ли это как-то обойти и поставить SSL сертификат на *localhost*?
Пытался сделать самоподписанный SSL сертификат, но он говорит, что сайт не надежен.
Линукс сервер запущен на *Node.js* на *Selectel'е* с помощью *Nginx*, скрипт сервера запускаю демонизатором *pm2*.
Обязательно ли нужно оформлять домен, или можно как-то сделать сертифицированный SSL на *localhost*?

Comment: «Он требует домен и субдомен» — нет, не требует. // «на localhost» — нельзя, Let's Encrypt никак не сможет проверить, что вы являетесь владельцем домена localhost (потому что вы им и не являетесь). // «он говорит, что сайт не надежен» — просто добавьте свой самоподписанный сертификат в доверенные да и всё, не?

Comment: @andreymal, это через код делать или через nginx?

Comment: Это делать в настройках того клиента (браузера), который считает сертификат ненадёжным

Comment: @andreymal, а для пользователей, которые будут пользоваться он будет надежным?

Comment: Зачем использовать localhost кому-то кроме вас?

Comment: @andreymal не, ну именно я перехожу на сайт через IPadress:port. Он просто нужен, чтобы инфу клиенту отправлять и он агрится, что сертификат не SSL.

Comment: Если переходить на IPadress, значит и сертификат должен быть для IPadress, а не для localhost. Let' Encrypt не выдаёт сертификаты для IP-адресов, но вы можете попробовать купить платный сертификат у какого-то другого центра сертификации (если найдётся такой, который согласится создать сертификат для IP-адреса). Если же вы хотите использовать именно бесплатный Let's Encrypt, то придётся прикручивать какой-то настоящий домен